# Asynctask and Handler class - can't share variable

Tags: java, android, service, android-asynctask, volatile

I have a Service which includes the Asynctask and Handler classes. AsyncTask and Handler should share a variable. I use the static volatile variable `isSendMessage` because I think there are two threads, but I'm not sure. The problem is that the variable in the while loop doesn't change. I don't know where my mistake is. Here is a snippet of my code.

```java
    public class Services extends Service  {

    static volatile boolean isSendMessage = false;

     @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

     @Override
        public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
             new ConnectionServerAsyncTask().execute();
             return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public class ConnectionServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Result, Void> {
    private boolean finish = false;

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
     }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      while(!finish){
         Log.i("isSendMessage",String.valueOf(isSendMessage));
          }
    }

      @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

  }

    public static class MessageHandler extends Handler{

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
               Log.i("MessageHandler","handleMessage");
               isSendMessage = true;              
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onPostExecute() automatically uses the UI thread so there's not really a need to use a handler in combination with async task. Just write code you want executed there like you would anywhere else.

Also for the loop while(!finish), I didn't see anyplace where finish is set to true.

Comment: the Asynctask class is for the connection to the server. I need the handler because I want to send data from the activity to the service and the service Asynctask send data to server.

Comment: You could declare static Boolean isSendMessage = false as a global variable at the very top of your activity. That should allow it to be shared.

Answer (score 0):

try removing static volatile.
replace it to `boolean isSendMessage = false;`